# Telephoto Supported Devices

Tags: android, camera

I am making an Android camera application. I need to implement telephoto feature in my application. I want to know which android devices support telephoto so that I can test my application. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for a list of devices, or some way to query dynamically whether a device has a telephoto lens? If the latter, what have you tried so far?

Comment: How are you defining "telephoto"? That is a very old term, not normally used in the world of smartphones. Do you mean optical zoom? Do you mean digital zoom? Do you mean something else?

Comment: ... a fax, maybe?

Comment: @CommonsWare its a commonly used term https://www.guidingtech.com/telephoto-lens-mobile-camera/